# Need Quartz Cron Expression to run scheduler every 4 hours starting at 00:30 am

Tags: cron, quartz

Quatz cron to run the job at 12:30am, 4:30am, 8:30am, 12:30pm, 4:30pm 8:30pm everyday

Can someone please help with this

Answer (score 0):

The expression you search for is:

```
0 30 0,4,8,12,16,20 * ? * /path/to/command
```

This will run 30 minutes from every hour in list